# Append content to an already rendered page with Pug-Jade in express.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I use Pug/Jade templates to render my content in express.js. I want to create a infinite scroll on client side. When the user press a button, can I through  an ajax call to append more contents to the same page using a Pug/Jade file?

I know that can return the results on client side and render them there, but I ask if it's possible on server side.

Something like this:

**cliend-index.js**

```
    $('#load-more').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/get_more_posts',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                last_received_id: last_received_id
            },
            success: function() {
                // do nothing as the content rendered on the server side
            },
            error: function() {
               // generate an error
            }

        });
    });
```

**sever-app.js**

```
app.post('/get_more_posts', function(req, res) {
    db.select_post({
        last_received_id: req.body.last_received_id
    }, function(query_res) {
        res.render('more-posts', {
            _POST_LIST: helper.prepare_posts_for_rendering(query_res)
        });
    });
});
```

Above the file **more-posts** used in render method, needs to  append the data to **index.pug** which is my index file.

Do I use some block for this? Is it possible to render the html and return the content to client, so in the end I'll append it using JQuery?

Comment: What's actually wrong with the code you posted? I haven't run it, but the idea seems fine if you just do something with the resulting html in the success callback.

Comment: @aw04 Ι don't want to send the rendered version of **more-posts.pug** to client as it is. I already have rendered the **index.pug** file. I want to append the html rendered through **more-posts.pug** to a container in **index.pug**.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your first sentence. I thought you were trying to render more posts and return them? All it seems like you're missing is taking that rendered content and appending it on the client side... but I may be misunderstanding your question

Comment: @aw04 yes that's right. But I don't know how.

Comment: @aw04 Oh stupid me. I found it. I'll post and answer now.

Comment: I posted an answer just now, likely what you already found

Answer (score 2):

Okay that was silly. All I wanted to do is to return the data from `res.render()` to a variable and send this variable back to ajax call.

So in the end I use something like this:

```
app.post('/get_more_posts', function(req, res) {
    db.select_post({
        last_received_id: req.body.last_received_id
    }, function(query_res) {
        var rendered = res.render('more-posts', {
            _POST_LIST: helper.prepare_posts_for_rendering(query_res)
        });
        res.status(200).send({ rendered: rendered });
    });
});
```

and handle it in ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're returning partial html from the server, all you're missing is to append it on the client side. So if you want to add it to a an element `#more-data`:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#more-data').html(data);
}
```

Comment: well kind of. :) Thank you. See my answer.

Comment: oh you just weren't sending the data back, ok. glad you figured it out